# SymmetricDS client throws AuthenticationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, symmetricds

```
INFO  [client-001-job-3] o.j.s.s.impl.DataLoaderService - Using registration URL of http://localhost:8080/sync/server/registration?nodeGroupId=client&externalId=001&syncURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fsync%2Fclient-001&schemaVersion=%3F&databaseType=H2&databaseVersion=1.4&symmetricVersion=3.11.9&deploymentType=client&hostName=XXXXXXX&ipAddress=XX3
ERROR [client-001-job-3] o.j.s.s.impl.RegistrationService - Unexpected error during registration: org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.AuthenticationException
org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.AuthenticationException: null
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openStream(HttpIncomingTransport.java:139)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openReader(HttpIncomingTransport.java:156)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromTransport(DataLoaderService.java:592)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromPull(DataLoaderService.java:302)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromPull(DataLoaderService.java:258)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RegistrationService.attemptToRegisterWithServer(RegistrationService.java:505)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RegistrationService.registerWithServer(RegistrationService.java:481)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PullService.pullData(PullService.java:89)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.PullJob.doJob(PullJob.java:48)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.AbstractJob.invoke(AbstractJob.java:227)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:298)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

I do not know why this symetricDS error occures.

Comment: Seems that the client managed to reach the server. Is there a corresponding log on the server? Always try to match the logs for a more complete picture

Comment: The last log on the server is still:
INFO  [server-job-1] o.j.s.route.DataGapFastDetector - Querying data in gaps from database took 7 ms
INFO  [server-job-1] o.j.s.route.DataGapFastDetector - Full gap analysis is done after 7 ms
The problem is on the client side when it oppens the connection:
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        switch (code) {
case WebConstants.SC_FORBIDDEN:
            httpTransportManager.clearSession(connection);
            throw new AuthenticationException();

This exception is thrown at the client site

Comment: Is springboot securing somehow the endpoint on the server?

Comment: OOOh, wait, i will add it ti my SecurityFilter. 
WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.s.impl.RegistrationService - Cannot register a client node unless a node group link exists so the registering node can receive configuration updates.  Please add a group link where the source group id is server and the target group id is client
WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.web.RegistrationUriHandler - client:001:? was not allowed to register.

Comment: But I have this in the servers database:
-- server sends changes to client when client pulls from server
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('server', 'client', 'W');

-- client sends changes to server when client pushes to server
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('client', 'server', 'P');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to register the clients /sync URL as well.

```
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> symServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new SymmetricServlet(), "/sync/*");
    bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return bean;
  }
```